# Moderation queues in Android Stack Overflow app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I'm often away from PC, and it would be nice to see the moderation queues implemented in the official mobile app.

Comment: Which app? The new Stack Overflow app or the Stack Exchange app?

Comment: @ale I see now, thanks for pointing it out! Searched for "modqueue", found nothing.

Comment: Does the mobile web site have mod tools?

Comment: If this is about the brand-new Stack **Overflow** app, as the title says, then it's not a duplicate of the linked question about the older Stack **Exchange** app.